# Geom_Line grouping error: How to properly connect points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot where the lines connect to their respective group, but both groups start from the same beginning point.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
FA_MRI_APOE

Condition Treatment Age (Months) Region avg_FA sd_FA
<fctr> <chr> <fctr><chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
APOE2   Sham    3.5 CC  0.1990432   NA
APOE2   Sham    3.5 EC  0.2269353   NA
APOE2   Sham    3.5 HP  0.2253147   NA
APOE2   Sham    3.5 TH  0.3257256   NA
APOE2   Sham    7.5 CC  0.3093073   0.08619885
APOE2   Sham    7.5 EC  0.2255272   0.07652789
APOE2   Sham    7.5 HP  0.2897462   0.02708867
APOE2   Sham    7.5 TH  0.2866555   0.03557000
APOE2   Sham    9.5 CC  0.1840524   NA
APOE2   Sham    9.5 EC  0.3347699   NA
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("APOE2", "APOE3", "APOE4", 
"PS19"), class = "factor"), Treatment = c("Sham", "Sham", "Sham", 
"Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", 
"Sham", "mTBI", "mTBI", "mTBI", "mTBI", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", 
"Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "mTBI", "mTBI", "mTBI", 
"mTBI"), `Age (Months)` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("3.5", "7.5", "9.5"), class = "factor"), 
    Region = c("CC", "EC", "HP", "TH", "CC", "EC", "HP", "TH", 
    "CC", "EC", "HP", "TH", "CC", "EC", "HP", "TH", "CC", "EC", 
    "HP", "TH", "CC", "EC", "HP", "TH", "CC", "EC", "HP", "TH"
    ), avg_FA = c(0.199043221771717, 0.226935303, 0.225314745679497, 
    0.325725596398115, 0.309307302666667, 0.225527225666667, 
    0.289746216333333, 0.286655532, 0.184052395, 0.334769852, 
    0.34609792, 0.237951324, 0.303560921, 0.233204448, 0.30656011, 
    0.296695315, 0.256386488908901, 0.2787716635, 0.270610670559108, 
    0.265520500484854, 0.289559764, 0.337927988666667, 0.370170086833333, 
    0.352682695666667, 0.391898785, 0.112882524, 0.29461883, 
    0.258586437), sd_FA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0861988548059451, 
    0.0765278945487883, 0.0270886655892862, 0.0355699995442251, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0332061193275388, 0.0121768772823131, 
    0.0441863595350275, 0.063138972154108, 0.11418350071109, 
    0.0829486022039601, 0.0831420050073176, 0.0689368863615038, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), groups = structure(list(
    Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("APOE2", 
    "APOE3", "APOE4", "PS19"), class = "factor"), Treatment = c("Sham", 
    "Sham", "Sham", "mTBI", "Sham", "Sham", "mTBI"), `Age (Months)` = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("3.5", "7.5", "9.5"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20, 21:24, 
        25:28), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

And here is what I wrote to generate the plot:

```
ggplot(FA_MRI_APOE, aes(x = `Age (Months)`,
                        y = avg_FA,
                        color = factor(Treatment, levels = c("Sham", "mTBI")),
                        group = factor(Treatment, levels = c("Sham", "mTBI")))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = avg_FA - sd_FA,
                    ymax = avg_FA + sd_FA),
                width = 0.1) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  geom_line(group = 1) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = `Age (Months)`,
                  y = `Mean`),
              position = position_jitter(0.1),
              alpha = 0.5,
              size = 1.5,
              data = FA_MRI_APOE_raw) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment", values = c("#0074C1", "#F7530B")) +
  facet_grid(Region ~ Condition) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

The generated plot looks like this:
[image]

Essentially, I want the point for the 3.5 month old group to be the same starting point for the sham and mTBI data, but for it to then break off and connect to the points for its respective groups at the 7.5 and 9.5 month old points. Right now, it is just connecting all of the data points, which is not what I want, but I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated :).

Comment: Why are you overriding `group=` in your call to `geom_line`? Shouldn't it be `group=Treatment`? BTW, you have the makings of a great question with code and sample data, but your sample data does not include any `mTBI` data, so we're not really able to test. Can you provide a sample that supports at least all of "CC", with boe "APOE2" and "APOE4", and both "Sham" and "mTBI"? (Even better, please, can you paste the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is the sample I just described? The output from `dput` is less ambiguous and easier to work with. Thanks!)

Comment: In case your data doesn't look like this already, you will want to add rows for age 3.5 so that both Treatments have an observation there. It seems to me like it might be simplest to solve this for one facet, eg APOE2 / CC, and then it'll be trivial to expand it to the others.

Comment: @JonSpring I'm not able to add rows for age 3.5 with both treatment groups. At 3.5, it is only 1 treatment group, then it is divided between the 2 treatment groups for the last 2 time points shown in the image

Comment: @r2evans when I typed group=Treatment, I received the same output that is shown in the image above. I also apologize in advance, I'm not sure what you are asking me to do. I only plotted a small portion of the data since it's a rather large df (over 600 rows in total)

Comment: You have no `mTBI` data for `3.5`-month patients. Do you need to duplicate it into the mTBI data so that the lines can diverge from the same point?

Comment: Is that the only way to get the plot that I am trying to generate? I assume that would change the way the 3.5 data points would look since blue & orange would be overlapping, and that's not what I want @r2evans

Comment: Not sure, see my answer. If that doesn't address it, is it possible for you to photoshop one of the facets and/or draw (with colors? perhaps crayons :-) what one facet _should_ look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data has no `3.5`/`mTBI` rows, and you say you want the `mTBI` lines to start from the `3.5` points, I suggest we need to duplicate the `3.5`-month rows, reclassify them as `mTBI`, and append them to the data.

Additionally, we need to remove `group=1` from your `geom_line`, as it is blocking us from doing what we need with the lines. In this case, it then inherits from the original call to `ggplot` with its aesthetic `group = factor(Treatment, levels = c("Sham", "mTBI"))`.

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
ungroup(FA_MRI_APOE) %>%
  filter(`Age (Months)` == "3.5") %>%
  mutate(Treatment = "mTBI") %>%
  bind_rows(FA_MRI_APOE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Age (Months)`,
                        y = avg_FA,
                        color = factor(Treatment, levels = c("Sham", "mTBI")),
                        group = factor(Treatment, levels = c("Sham", "mTBI")))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = avg_FA - sd_FA,
                    ymax = avg_FA + sd_FA),
                width = 0.1) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  geom_line() +
  # geom_jitter(aes(x = `Age (Months)`,
  #                 y = `Mean`),
  #             position = position_jitter(0.1),
  #             alpha = 0.5,
  #             size = 1.5,
  #             data = FA_MRI_APOE_raw) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment", values = c("#0074C1", "#F7530B")) +
  facet_grid(Region ~ Condition) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

I commented out the `geom_points` as I don't have the `FA_MRI_APOE_raw` data.

You mentioned the possibility of extra points being a problem. If it doesn't look right for you, we can filter out the 3.5 and mTBI data for the points alone by replacing the `geom_point` above with

```r
  geom_point(size = 2.5, data = ~ filter(., `Age (Months)` != "3.5" | Treatment != "mTBI")) +
```

Comment: Okay this is EXACTLY what I needed and it worked perfectly!!! I'm able to follow it as well to see what all you did :). Thank you so much!

Comment: ... and it certainly seems like there are significant differences in APOE4 and mTBI-vs-Sham :-)

Comment: Very nice and clever!